# Get value of node from XML using loop

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Trying to loop though my XML data and assign to text fields. Not get a specific error but I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way I am referencing the data and assign it to the .text box. I am also having issues with getting the length of my xml so I know how many times to loop. Please Help. THANKS!

first a summary of my XML:

```
<Worksheet>
   <Row>
    <Data>Last Name</Data>
    <Data>First Name</Data>
    <Data>Ext.</Data>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Data>Smith</Data>
    <Data>Liz</Data>
    <Data>103</Data>
   </Row>
   <Row >
    <Data>Johns</Data>
    <Data>Jason</Data>
    <Data>116</Data>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Data>Potts</Data>
    <Data>Cheryl</Data>
    <Data>131</Data>
   </Row>
</Worksheet>
```

Now the AS3 that should loop through and assign values from the XML into text fields:

**//HAVING ISSUES GETTING THE LENGTH OF myXML**

```
                for (i = 0; i < myXML.Worksheet.length(); i++){

                trace(["in for loop" + i]);
                                 //Create new text_holder from linked MC
                var item:text_holder = new text_holder();
                 //add text holder to stage
                scroll_box.addChild(item);
```

**//NOW I WANT TO ASSIGN THE VALUES OF THE FIRST THREE DATA NODES IN THE LOOPS CURRENT ROW TO DYNAMIC TEXT FIELDS**

```
                        item.first_name.text = myXML.Worksheet.Row[i].Data[1];
                        item.last_name.text = myXML.Worksheet.Row[i].Data[0];
                        item.ext.text = myXML.Worksheet.Row[i].Data[2];
                            current_y_right = current_y_right  + 131;
                            item.x = current_x_right;
                            item.y = current_y_right;

                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. Use `.text()` on a node to get its value.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("test.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded, false, 0, true);

function loaded(evt:Event):void
{
    var xml:XML = new XML(evt.currentTarget.data);
    for(var i:int=0;i<xml.children().length();i++)
    {
        var _row = xml.children()[i];
        for(var j:int=0;j<_row.children().length();j++)
        {
            var _data = _row.children()[j];
            trace(_data.text());
        }
    }
}
```

If desired (I recommend it), store each node in an array or an object for outside reference.

Comment: I see I was telling the loop to get the value. Thanks! I will test it now.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
for(var i : int = 0; i < myXML.Worksheet.Row.length(); i++){
... = myXML.Worksheet.Row[i].Data[0];
}
```

or if Worksheet is the root node you only need

```
myXML.Row.length();
```

but you can also use

```
myXML..Row.length();
```

if you dont care how far down in the xml it is nested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all skip the root node when referencing XML elements. So no myXML.Worksheet.Row[i], instead use myXML.Row[i]. Secondly (and keeping in mind the previous comment), you're iterating over Rows so you need myXML.Row.length() instead of myXML.Worksheet.length().